# PHP HSV to RGB formula comprehension

Tags: php, colors, rgb, hsv

I can convert **RGB** values to **HSV** with the following code...

```
 $r = $r/255;
 $g = $g/255;
 $b = $b/255;

 $h = 0;
 $s = 0;
 $v = 0;

 $min = min(min($r, $g),$b);
 $max = max(max($r, $g),$b);

 $r = $max-$min;
 $v = $max;


 if($r == 0){
  $h = 0;
  $s = 0;
 }
 else {
  $s = $r / $max;

  $hr = ((($max - $r) / 6) + ($r / 2)) / $r;
  $hg = ((($max - $g) / 6) + ($r / 2)) / $r;
  $hb = ((($max - $b) / 6) + ($r / 2)) / $r;

  if ($r == $max) $h = $hb - $hg;
  else if($g == $max) $h = (1/3) + $hr - $hb;
  else if ($b == $max) $h = (2/3) + $hg - $hr;

  if ($h < 0)$h += 1;
  if ($h > 1)$h -= 1;
 }
```

But how do you convert **HSV** *to* **RGB** in **PHP**???

The following is on wikipedia but I don't understand it,

I'm guessing it's pretty obvious

[image]

Comment: There are formulas here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_color_space#Conversion_from_RGB_to_HSL_or_HSV

Comment: I know but can someone explain the formulas

Comment: Is this formula **REALLY** working for you? Because you re-introduced $r variable (nothing like dynamic language...).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP function to convert HSL to RGB or Hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423641/php-function-to-convert-hsl-to-rgb-or-hex)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is for the the HSV values in the range `[0,1]` (and giving RGB values in the range `[0,1]`, instead of `{0, 1, ..., 255}`:

```
function HSVtoRGB(array $hsv) {
    list($H,$S,$V) = $hsv;
    //1
    $H *= 6;
    //2
    $I = floor($H);
    $F = $H - $I;
    //3
    $M = $V * (1 - $S);
    $N = $V * (1 - $S * $F);
    $K = $V * (1 - $S * (1 - $F));
    //4
    switch ($I) {
        case 0:
            list($R,$G,$B) = array($V,$K,$M);
            break;
        case 1:
            list($R,$G,$B) = array($N,$V,$M);
            break;
        case 2:
            list($R,$G,$B) = array($M,$V,$K);
            break;
        case 3:
            list($R,$G,$B) = array($M,$N,$V);
            break;
        case 4:
            list($R,$G,$B) = array($K,$M,$V);
            break;
        case 5:
        case 6: //for when $H=1 is given
            list($R,$G,$B) = array($V,$M,$N);
            break;
    }
    return array($R, $G, $B);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by
This is for the the HSV values in the range [0,1] (and giving RGB values in the range [0,1], instead of {0, 1, ..., 255}
Please explain

Comment: I mean the values must be between 0 and 1.

Comment: Ohhh so instead of h:0, s:100 and v: 100 it should be h:0 s:1 v:1

Comment: The simplest approach I've seen so far.

Comment: To translate from Deg/Perc/Perc, like you're used to, to [0,1], divide the hue by 60, and sat and lum by 100.

Answer (score 5):

Translation of rolls answer for **HSL** from C to PHP

```
function ColorHSLToRGB($h, $s, $l){

        $r = $l;
        $g = $l;
        $b = $l;
        $v = ($l <= 0.5) ? ($l * (1.0 + $s)) : ($l + $s - $l * $s);
        if ($v > 0){
              $m;
              $sv;
              $sextant;
              $fract;
              $vsf;
              $mid1;
              $mid2;

              $m = $l + $l - $v;
              $sv = ($v - $m ) / $v;
              $h *= 6.0;
              $sextant = floor($h);
              $fract = $h - $sextant;
              $vsf = $v * $sv * $fract;
              $mid1 = $m + $vsf;
              $mid2 = $v - $vsf;

              switch ($sextant)
              {
                    case 0:
                          $r = $v;
                          $g = $mid1;
                          $b = $m;
                          break;
                    case 1:
                          $r = $mid2;
                          $g = $v;
                          $b = $m;
                          break;
                    case 2:
                          $r = $m;
                          $g = $v;
                          $b = $mid1;
                          break;
                    case 3:
                          $r = $m;
                          $g = $mid2;
                          $b = $v;
                          break;
                    case 4:
                          $r = $mid1;
                          $g = $m;
                          $b = $v;
                          break;
                    case 5:
                          $r = $v;
                          $g = $m;
                          $b = $mid2;
                          break;
              }
        }
        return array('r' => $r * 255.0, 'g' => $g * 255.0, 'b' => $b * 255.0);
}
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34363975/3437608) for the reverse to this function, and added capabilities.

Answer (score 5):

Found this post too late, my alternate take on it:

**hsv2rgb function PHP**

*hue: 0-360, sat: 0-100, val: 0-100*

```
  function hsv2rgb($hue,$sat,$val) {;
    $rgb = array(0,0,0);
    //calc rgb for 100% SV, go +1 for BR-range
    for($i=0;$i<4;$i++) {
      if (abs($hue - $i*120)<120) {
        $distance = max(60,abs($hue - $i*120));
        $rgb[$i % 3] = 1 - (($distance-60) / 60);
      }
    }
    //desaturate by increasing lower levels
    $max = max($rgb);
    $factor = 255 * ($val/100);
    for($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {
      //use distance between 0 and max (1) and multiply with value
      $rgb[$i] = round(($rgb[$i] + ($max - $rgb[$i]) * (1 - $sat/100)) * $factor);
    }
    $rgb['html'] = sprintf('#%02X%02X%02X', $rgb[0], $rgb[1], $rgb[2]);
    return $rgb;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private class HSLPixel{
        double hue;
        double saturation;
        double lightness;

        .... your code
}

public Color HSLToRGB(HSLPixel pixel){

            double v;
            double r,g,b;
            double l = pixel.lightness;
            double h = pixel.hue;
            double s = pixel.saturation;

            r = l;   // default to gray
            g = l;
            b = l;
            v = (l <= 0.5) ? (l * (1.0 + s)) : (l + s - l * s);
            if (v > 0){
                  double m;
                  double sv;
                  int sextant;
                  double fract, vsf, mid1, mid2;

                  m = l + l - v;
                  sv = (v - m ) / v;
                  h *= 6.0;
                  sextant = (int)h;
                  fract = h - sextant;
                  vsf = v * sv * fract;
                  mid1 = m + vsf;
                  mid2 = v - vsf;

                  switch (sextant)
                  {
                        case 0:
                              r = v;
                              g = mid1;
                              b = m;
                              break;
                        case 1:
                              r = mid2;
                              g = v;
                              b = m;
                              break;
                        case 2:
                              r = m;
                              g = v;
                              b = mid1;
                              break;
                        case 3:
                              r = m;
                              g = mid2;
                              b = v;
                              break;
                        case 4:
                              r = mid1;
                              g = m;
                              b = v;
                              break;
                        case 5:
                              r = v;
                              g = m;
                              b = mid2;
                              break;
                  }
            }
            Color rgb = new Color((int)(r * 255.0), (int)(g * 255.0), (int)(b * 255.0));
            return rgb;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[ColorJizz](http://code.google.com/p/colorjizz/) allows you to convert from/to many formats. There is a PHP version too.