# Altering Saturation of #RGB Color: Whats Missing Here?

Tags: php, function, colors, hex

Below is a concept for a brightness/saturation alterarion programm with `brightness()` and  `saturation()`.

```
function brightness($colorstr, $steps) { 
    ...
    return sprintf("%02x%02x%02x", $r, $g, $b);
} 
function saturation(){ 
    ...
    return sprintf("%02x%02x%02x", $r, $g, $b);
}
```

Are there any existing simple to use fashions online to complement this ane make the following possible:

```
$color2 = saturation($color,-10); /* less staurated*/
$color3 = saturation($color,+10); /* more staurated*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saturation and brightness cannot be handled the same (one could argue that your aren't handling brightness correctly using this code but it's probably close enough). See this question [RGB to HSV in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773698/rgb-to-hsv-in-php) for how to convert the color to an HSV value then you can modify the saturation (the S value). Then convert back using the answer to this question [PHP HSV to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597417/php-hsv-to-rgb-formula-comprehension).

Comment: Indeed +1 for perfection but for now Im really fine something easy, simple and rough. By the way, I find the incorrect values PHP giving me from this indeed incorrect program, fascinatingly surprising and somehow I experience them as correct. But thats personal, my friend:)

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer this with code but I this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Hue_and_chroma) about hue and chroma describes the theory very well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily using the phpColors library:

- https://github.com/mexitek/phpColors

Once included in your project you can mess with the saturation like this:

```
use Mexitek\PHPColors\Color;

// Convert my HEX
$myBlue = Color::hexToHsl("#336699");

// Get crazy with the saturation
$myBlue["S"] = 0.2;

// Gimme my new color!!
echo Color::hslToHex($myBlue);
```