# Get elements background color after webkit-filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get a color from an element on my screen after the initial color has been ran through `-webkit-filter` on the CSS. nd apply that color onto another element.

HTML

```
   <div id="Div1" style="background-color: rgb(166,187,207);"></div>
   <br>
   <div id="Div2"></div>
```

CSS

```
  #Div1{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-filter: saturate(5);
  }
```

Javascript

```
   var inDiv1 = document.getElementById("Div1");
   var dColorx = inDiv1.style.backgroundColor;

   var inDiv2 = document.getElementById("Div2");
   inDiv2.innerHTML += '<svg width="400" height="110">'+
                       '<rect width="300" height="100" '+
                       'style="fill:'+ dColorx +';'+
                       'stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"></svg>';
```

I need the rect inside of Div2 to be the same color as Div1 currently.

```
 Div1 default color rgb(166,187,207).
 Div1 post filter color rgb(94,199,255). <-- need to get this color
```

I also used a RGB to HSL converters I've found on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806483/increase-or-decrease-color-saturation), but the colors were off by quite a bit. If I'm not making sense, I do apologize. I've been up all night trying to get this to work.

If anyone can help me it would greatly be appreciated! 
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/JfKEL/

Comment: Do you absolutely need an svg element inside Div2 or just the background image to be the same.

Comment: @Stefan Unfortunately yes. I'm drawing objects onto the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how you would get the colour after applying the filter exactly but you can use the same colour for your svg elements and re-apply the filter. Your svg output will be something like this:

```
<svg width="400" height="110">
    <filter id="saturate">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="saturate" values="5" />
    </filter>
    <g filter="url(#saturate)">
        <rect width="300" height="100" '+ 'style="fill:'+ dColorx + '; stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)">
    </g>
</svg>
```

[**Working jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JfKEL/2/)

Comment: Thanks! this will do just fine!

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the functions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353211/hsl-to-rgb-color-conversion) you should be able to achieve what you want using the following:

```
var inDiv1 = document.getElementById("Div1");
var dColorx = inDiv1.style.backgroundColor.replace(/[^0-9$,]/g, '').split(',');

var hsl= rgbToHsl(dColorx[0], dColorx[1], dColorx[2]);
hsl[1] = hsl[1] * 5;
var rgb = hslToRgb(hsl[0], hsl[1], hsl[2]);
var newColor = 'rgb(' + rgb[0] + ',' + rgb[1] + ',' + rgb[2] + ');'

var inDiv2 = document.getElementById("Div2");
inDiv2.innerHTML += '<svg width="400" height="110">' +
    '<rect width="300" height="100" ' +
    'style="fill:' + newColor +
    ';stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"></svg>';
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/JfKEL/6/)