# Replicate the partial CSS Grayscale filter in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I can convert an image to fully grayscale version easily. What I can't do is replicate partial grayscaling. For example,

```
.image {
  filter: grayscale(0.5);
}
```

This filter applied in CSS will only turn the image partially grayscale. I want to do the same in JavaScript on a canvas image. Can anyone please help me with that?

**I know how to make an image fully grayscale. I am looking for a way to make the effect less intense and I want to do it using JavaScript canvas.**

[image]

All the images above have the grayscale filter applied with different intensities.

Comment: By partially, do you mean a portion of the canvas?

Comment: @Roberrrt No, Let me add an image. :)

Comment: Layer grayscale image over original image and lower the opacity? Or other way around

Comment: @JariPekkala something like that but I have no idea how to do it. :)

Comment: @Roberrrt I have added an image :)

Comment: @NeenaVivek, Have a look my answer. Hope it will help you.

Comment: You're using the wrong words. You don't make it greayscale by some value, you actually "desaturate" it. Once you write that in google there's many results. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806483/increase-or-decrease-color-saturation

Comment: @JonasGrumann but staturation and grayscale are two different filters in CSS. Do they work exactly the same way?

Comment: They work semi-inverted. Grayscale actually applies a black/white layer over the existing colors, whereas saturation (or desaturation in this case) **removes** the color from the original image.

Comment: Mmmh you got me thinking there. Google says: Saturation defines a range from pure color (100%) to gray (0%) at a constant lightness level

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "saturation"

```
ctx.drawImage(colourImage,0,0); // draw colour image onto canvas
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "saturation"; // set the comp mode
ctx.fillStyle = "hsl(0," + Math.floor(amount) + "%,50%); // set a colour with saturation 0-100

// OR use RGB for finer control
ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF"; // white no colour
ctx.globalAlpha = amount; // the amount of saturation you wish to remove 0-1

ctx.fillRect(0,0,colourImage.width,colourImage.height);
```

There are many effect that can be created by using the globalCompositeOperation types `"source-over,lighter,darker,source-atop,source-in,source-out,destination-over,destination-atop,destination-in,destination-out,copy,xor,multiply,screen,overlay,color-dodge,color-burn,hard-light,soft-light,difference,exclusion,hue,saturation,color,luminosity"`

Not all browsers support all operation (Most notable is FF not supporting `darker` use `multiply` instead) But chrome, Edge, and Firefox support all the others listed above.

More on saturation and Colour to Black and white][2] below, both methods give very fine control over the amount of the effect

**Increase the Color Contrast With Saturation**

Increase the saturation level of an image with

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'saturation';
```

The amount of the effect can be controled with the alpha setting or the amount of saturation in the fill overlay

```
// Render the image
ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-atop';
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

// set the composite operation
ctx.globalCompositeOperation ='saturation';
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.globalAlpha = alpha;  // alpha 0 = no effect 1 = full effect
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
```

[image]

**Colour to Black and White**

Remove color from an image via

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'color';
```

The amount of the effect can be controled with the alpha setting

```
// Render the image
ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-atop';
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

// set the composite operation
ctx.globalCompositeOperation='color';
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.globalAlpha = alpha;  // alpha 0 = no effect 1 = full effect
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
```

[image]

Comment: In addition to this, Firefox as well as Chrome/Opera do support CSS filters with context directly now, so you can set `ctx.filter = "grayscale(0.5)";` Not sure about Edge though, and there should be little difference in regards to performance as CSS and context blending modes are the same. Just mentioning this as a future option which can simplify the whole process when fully supported.

Comment: using `globalCompositeOperation = "saturation"` was the best way I could find for removing the colour from a polygon area of an existing canvas image, thanks!