# percentage to shade of gray

Tags: hex, rgb

I'm working on a visual data tool where I have a min and a max value. All entries will have a value that falls somewhere inbetween those. I'd like to have my bars with coloring that reflects this min and max value. Such as  a 0 value would get #ffffff and a Maxed 100 would be #000000 and 50 would be #888888

So my problem is, how do I convert this? I'm not sure what the conversion would be.

Comment: Obviously the answer is 50% (sorry, couldn't resist).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Percentage to Hexcolor in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655704/percentage-to-hexcolor-in-php)

Comment: @BoristheSpider #888 is 47% black.

Comment: The key is that when dealing with shades of gray, each "two-digit" chunk of your "six-digit" hex color code will always have the same value....this should give you a clue on how to achieve what you want.

Comment: I think you don't need to add the java/php tags here at least that you provide some code related to what you've tried to do this. Please update the question with code or remove the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get percentage from 0 to 100
2. Subtract percentage from 100
3. Multiply value times 255
4. Convert to integer
5. Convert to two digit Hex
6. Concatenate Value with itself three times to get six digit hex
7. Profit.