# interpolate color over bresenham line in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, graphics, 3d, bresenham

I specifically need to adapt the java bresenham implementation here http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm#Java with smooth color interpolation over the line.

I'm aware of this solution [smooth color interpolation along a "bresenham" line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878029/smooth-color-interpolation-along-a-bresenham-line) but unfortunately all my attempts to adapt both it's bresenham implementation with the rest of my code or the answers for color to my current implementation have gone poorly.

Here's the code as far as I've gotten it but the result is either only the first color(red) or a weird alternating between the final color (blue) and yellow. If anyone could help it would be really appreciated, thanks!

```
int d = 0;

int dx = Math.abs(x2 - x1);
int dy = Math.abs(y2 - y1);

int dx2 = 2 * dx; // slope scaling factors to
int dy2 = 2 * dy; // avoid floating point

int ix = x1 < x2 ? 1 : -1; // increment direction
int iy = y1 < y2 ? 1 : -1;

int x = x1;
int y = y1;

if (dx >= dy) 
{
    while (true) 
    {    
        framebuffer[0][x][y] = c0.R*(1-d)+c1.R*d;
        framebuffer[1][x][y] = c0.G*(1-d)+c1.G*d;
        framebuffer[2][x][y] = c0.B*(1-d)+c1.B*d;
        if (x == x2)
            break;
        x += ix;
        d += dy2;
        if (d > dx) 
        {
            y += iy;
            d -= dx2;
        }
    }
} 
else 
{
    while (true) 
    {
        int p = 2*dy-dx;
        framebuffer[0][x][y] = c0.R*(1-d)+c1.R*d;
        framebuffer[1][x][y] = c0.G*(1-d)+c1.G*d;
        framebuffer[2][x][y] = c0.B*(1-d)+c1.B*d;
        if (y == y2)
            break;
        y += iy;
        d += dx2;
        if (d > dy) 
        {
            x += ix;
            d -= dy2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, my immediate issue is, you need to know the number of points in the line, otherwise it's impossible to interpolate the change between colors (a blend between colors is based on the normalised distance (0-1) between the two colors (0 been the first color, 1 been the last color) - so, you need to know how many points you are drawing and how far through the line you are to be able to determine the what color you should be using

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm a little confused because the Bresenham Algorithm in theory is calculating that here, no? I can say I have the delta x and y of the 2 points calculated but before this algorithm runs I think it's impossible to say the number of points. In fact I'm not even sure it is represented in points by the end, only the number of increments on either x or y. Should I perhaps sum the increments?

Comment: But you need to know how many points the algorithm will create in order to be able to create a blended color (and I'm talking about the implementation of the algorithm, not the algorithm itself)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hm okay I get what you mean. I've seen this 

`if (Math.abs(x2-x1) >= Math.abs(y2-y1))
{

      pixNum = Math.abs(x2-x1);

}
else
{

       pixNum = Math.abs(y2-y1);

}`

I will mess around with that

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to create color that is a blend of two colors, you need to know the distance between the colors at which you want to blend.

The problem with the way that your algorithm is currently implement is, you don't know the number of points which might be needed to create an individual line, so you can't calculate the color of the segement.

So, I modified your algorthim to return a `List` of `Point`s, instead of drawing them.

```
public class Bresenham {
    public static List<Point> line(Point from, Point to) {
        List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>(32);
        // delta of exact value and rounded value of the dependent variable
        int d = 0;

        int dx = Math.abs(from.x - to.x);
        int dy = Math.abs(from.y - to.y);

        int deltaX = 2 * dx; // slope scaling factors to
        int deltaY = 2 * dy; // avoid floating point

        int ix = to.x < from.x ? 1 : -1; // increment direction
        int iy = to.y < from.y ? 1 : -1;

        int x = to.x;
        int y = to.y;

        if (dx >= dy) {
            while (true) {
                points.add(new Point(x, y));
                if (x == from.x) {
                    break;
                }
                x += ix;
                d += deltaY;
                if (d > dx) {
                    y += iy;
                    d -= deltaX;
                }
            }
        } else {
            while (true) {
                points.add(new Point(x, y));
                if (y == from.y) {
                    break;
                }
                y += iy;
                d += deltaX;
                if (d > dy) {
                    x += ix;
                    d -= deltaY;
                }
            }
        }
        return points;
    }
}
```

This now tells us how many points are in the line.  From this we can calculate the progression value (0-1) along the line, which will allow use to generate a color blending algorthim.

I then took the [`ColorBand`](https://gist.github.com/RustyKnight/552e6d7ed08d84125096da3e26dd7caf) implementation I have, which is based on [Color fading algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223065/color-fading-algorithm/13223818#13223818) and [Color fading algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223065/color-fading-algorithm/13223818#13223818) (and a few other) examples.

From that, I can calculate the color of the line segment based normalised progression through the line points.

For example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public final class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {
        private List<List<Point>> lines;
        private ColorBand colorBand;

        public TestPane() {
            lines = new ArrayList<>(4);
            lines.add(Bresenham.line(new Point(0, 0), new Point(200, 200)));
            lines.add(Bresenham.line(new Point(100, 0), new Point(100, 200)));
            lines.add(Bresenham.line(new Point(200, 0), new Point(0, 200)));
            lines.add(Bresenham.line(new Point(0, 100), new Point(200, 100)));

            colorBand = new ColorBand(
                    new float[]{0f, 0.5f, 1f},
                    new Color[]{Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE}
            );
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            for (List<Point> line : lines) {
                Point lastPoint = null;
                float progress = 0f;
                for (int index = 0; index < line.size(); index++) {
                    progress = (float) index / (float) line.size();
                    Point nextPoint = line.get(index);
                    if (lastPoint == null) {
                        lastPoint = nextPoint;
                        continue;
                    }
                    g2d.setColor(colorBand.colorAt(progress));
                    g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(lastPoint, nextPoint));
                    lastPoint = nextPoint;
                }
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public static class Bresenham {
        public static List<Point> line(Point from, Point to) {
            List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>(32);
            // delta of exact value and rounded value of the dependent variable
            int d = 0;

            int dx = Math.abs(from.x - to.x);
            int dy = Math.abs(from.y - to.y);

            int deltaX = 2 * dx; // slope scaling factors to
            int deltaY = 2 * dy; // avoid floating point

            int ix = to.x < from.x ? 1 : -1; // increment direction
            int iy = to.y < from.y ? 1 : -1;

            int x = to.x;
            int y = to.y;

            if (dx >= dy) {
                while (true) {
                    points.add(new Point(x, y));
                    if (x == from.x) {
                        break;
                    }
                    x += ix;
                    d += deltaY;
                    if (d > dx) {
                        y += iy;
                        d -= deltaX;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                while (true) {
                    points.add(new Point(x, y));
                    if (y == from.y) {
                        break;
                    }
                    y += iy;
                    d += deltaX;
                    if (d > dy) {
                        x += ix;
                        d -= deltaY;
                    }
                }
            }
            return points;
        }
    }

    public class ColorBand {

        private float[] fractions;
        private Color[] colors;

        public ColorBand(float[] fractions, Color[] colors) {
            this.fractions = fractions;
            this.colors = colors;
        }

        public Color colorAt(float progress) {
            Color color = null;
            if (fractions != null) {
                if (colors != null) {
                    if (fractions.length == colors.length) {
                        int[] indicies = getFractionIndicies(progress);

                        float[] range = new float[]{fractions[indicies[0]], fractions[indicies[1]]};
                        Color[] colorRange = new Color[]{colors[indicies[0]], colors[indicies[1]]};

                        float max = range[1] - range[0];
                        float value = progress - range[0];
                        float weight = value / max;

                        color = blend(colorRange[0], colorRange[1], 1f - weight);
                    } else {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Fractions and colours must have equal number of elements");
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Colours can't be null");
                }
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Fractions can't be null");
            }
            return color;
        }

        protected int[] getFractionIndicies(float progress) {
            int[] range = new int[2];

            int startPoint = 0;
            while (startPoint < fractions.length && fractions[startPoint] <= progress) {
                startPoint++;
            }

            if (startPoint >= fractions.length) {
                startPoint = fractions.length - 1;
            }

            range[0] = startPoint - 1;
            range[1] = startPoint;

            return range;
        }

        protected Color blend(Color color1, Color color2, double ratio) {
            float r = (float) ratio;
            float ir = (float) 1.0 - r;

            float rgb1[] = new float[3];
            float rgb2[] = new float[3];

            color1.getColorComponents(rgb1);
            color2.getColorComponents(rgb2);

            float red = rgb1[0] * r + rgb2[0] * ir;
            float green = rgb1[1] * r + rgb2[1] * ir;
            float blue = rgb1[2] * r + rgb2[2] * ir;

            if (red < 0) {
                red = 0;
            } else if (red > 255) {
                red = 255;
            }
            if (green < 0) {
                green = 0;
            } else if (green > 255) {
                green = 255;
            }
            if (blue < 0) {
                blue = 0;
            } else if (blue > 255) {
                blue = 255;
            }

            Color color = null;
            try {
                color = new Color(red, green, blue);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException exp) {
                NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
                System.out.println(nf.format(red) + "; " + nf.format(green) + "; " + nf.format(blue));
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
            return color;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, because I'm curious, I modified the lines so some are draw backwards (bottom to top)

```
lines.add(Bresenham.line(new Point(0, 0), new Point(200, 200)));
lines.add(Bresenham.line(new Point(100, 200), new Point(100, 0)));
lines.add(Bresenham.line(new Point(0, 200), new Point(200, 0)));
lines.add(Bresenham.line(new Point(0, 100), new Point(200, 100)));
```

just to see what I would get...

[image]

Comment: This is wonderfully thorough, thank you - going to take time to go through this and will follow up later!