# Java - color between two colors from amount

Tags: java, colors

In my Java game I am making a health bar. The player's health can range from 0.0 to 100.0. I want to select a color between red and green depending on the player's health. If the health is 100.0, the color should be rgb(0, 255, 0). If the health is 0.0, the color should be rgb(255, 0, 0). Likewise, if the health = 50.0, then the color should be rgb(127, 127, 0). So the color it returns is a mixture between red and green depending on the health. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You may be doing your brain a disservice by not allowing it to try to write the code first itself, and you may be giving it an insult by not thinking that it is capable of doing so. I'm betting that it is. I say, give it a go first, and see what you come up with -- you may be pleasantly surprised.

Comment: Why the down-votes: because you've not shown any evidence of effort yet. Surely you've tried to solve this, so show us what you've got.

Comment: @MCMastery You've asked for code with zero effort. This is also a simple problem for anyone familiar with basic mathematics so it would be nice to see at least your attempt at a solution.

Comment: Take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223065/color-fading-algorithm/13223818#13223818) and [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270610/java-smooth-color-transition/21270957#21270957)

Comment: I sincerely hope that your future questions will show *some* evidence of effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something simple like this?

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class QuickTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(getColor(100).toString());
        System.out.println(getColor(75).toString());
        System.out.println(getColor(50).toString());
        System.out.println(getColor(25).toString());
        System.out.println(getColor(0).toString());
    }

    private static Color getColor(double currHp) {

        int green = ((int) (currHp / 100.0 * 255));
        int red = 255 - green;

        return new Color(red, green, 0);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
java.awt.Color[r=0,g=255,b=0]
java.awt.Color[r=64,g=191,b=0]
java.awt.Color[r=128,g=127,b=0]
java.awt.Color[r=192,g=63,b=0]
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
```

You could just use the `Color` returned directly, I am using `toString()` for prototyping.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I just came out of Algebra so sometimes I can't think of solutions as quickly :p

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want it to vary linearly (which seems plausible):

- Red: 255 - health * 2.55
- Green: health * 2.55
- Blue: 0

This works because if you want it to vary linearly, you will have something in the form A * health + B.