# Changing ContentPane background color over time

Tags: java, swing

I want to make background changing on a ContentPane over some period of time.

I have set default bg color in class

```
getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
```

and then on ButtonActionPerformed I want user to choose another color and then if not null the background should change to that color (the default one and the chosen one)

```
 Color bgC = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Choose color: ", Color.yellow);
    if (bgC != null)

    {
    Timer bT = new Timer (TIMER_DELAY, new ActionListener() {

     @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    getContentPane().setBackground(bgC);
    }
    });

    bT.start();
```

At the moment this works but it only changes the default color to new chosen color in time specified.

Comment: Do you want to cross fade the color?

Comment: Color blending [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270610/java-smooth-color-transition/21270957#21270957), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223065/color-fading-algorithm/13223818#13223818)

Comment: it does not need to be cross faded

Comment: Then, what's the question? If the above code works, what's wrong with it? What would you prefer it dd?

Comment: This way the bg changes from A to B in time T, but I would like it to have a blinking effect, A B A B A B A...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {
    public static class Blinker {
        private Color color1;
        private Timer timer;
        private Consumer<Color> setColor;
        private int timesBlinked;

        public Blinker(int delay, int blinkTimes, Color color1, Color color2, Consumer<Color> setColor) {
            this.color1 = color1;
            this.setColor = setColor;
            timesBlinked = 0;
            timer = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (timesBlinked < blinkTimes) {
                        if (timesBlinked % 2 == 0)
                            setColor.accept(color2);
                        else
                            setColor.accept(color1);
                        ++timesBlinked;
                    }
                    else
                        stop();
                }
            });
        }

        private void stop() {
            timer.stop();
        }

        public void start() {
            setColor.accept(color1);
            timer.start();
        }
    }

    public static void startBlink(int delay, int blinkTimes, Color color1, Color color2, Consumer<Color> setColor) {
        new Blinker(delay, blinkTimes, color1, color2, setColor).start();
    }

    public static class YourJFrame extends JFrame {
        public YourJFrame(String title) {
            super(title);

            JButton button = new JButton("Choose color");
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Color bgC = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Choose color: ", Color.YELLOW);
                    if (bgC != null)
                        startBlink(500, 7, getContentPane().getBackground(), bgC, c -> getContentPane().setBackground(c)); //Change the number arguments at will.
                }
            });

            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); //Just to keep the button centered.
            getContentPane().add(button);
            getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            pack();
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new YourJFrame("Blinker frame").setSize(250, 250);
    }
}
```

The `delay` argument of `startBlink` method determines the speed of the blinking.
The lower the number, the greater the speed.

The `blinkTimes` argument of `startBlink` method determines the number of times the colors will be blinked (alternated).
Remember to keep this an *odd* number of times, if you want the color to be finaly changed.

You may just copy the class `Blinker` and the method `startBlink` to your code to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Timer bT = new Timer (TIMER_DELAY, new ActionListener() {
    static final int[] startRGB = { 255, 255, 255 };
    int[] endRGB = { bg.getRed(), bg.getGreen(), bg.getBlue() };
    int pct = 0;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ++pct;

        int[] rgb = new int[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            rgb[i] = (pct*startRGB[i] + (100 - pct)*endRGB[]i]) / 100;
        }
        getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]));
        repaint(50L);
        if (pct == 100) {
            stop();
        }
    }
});
```

Here 100 steps, using a percentage `pct` and step size 1.

Timer should have `setRepeats(true)`.