# Delphi button transitions using VCL

Tags: delphi, vcl

Is there any way to do a transition (for example, a red button turning green when you click it) using Delphi with VCL? Something similar to CSS transitions...

Comment: just curios Do you know about easing functions?

Comment: If you say yes then that is your answer. :)

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout yes, I'm new to Delphi, is there any way I can use an animation loop? I can take it from there :P

Comment: Then you will be interested in [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/827808/control-animation-in-winforms) from codeProject c#, It is basically the same idea

Comment: That's using C# though, I can't seem to find any form of animation loop for Delphi :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the fruit of a quick research I made

- First you will need TAnimateEasing from
  [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/danimeasing/files/?source=navbar) sourceForge repository.
- This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841477/java-smooth-color-transition) written in java about how to go from one color to another.
- This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46796879/7579632) (mine) about a custom TSpeedButton.

And you combine all these to have this

[image]

and as you can see my translation of the java answer is not that good but that would be a different question. You asked how would you transition in a button and this is your answer

```
unit NCRSpeedButton;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Vcl.Controls, Winapi.Messages, Vcl.Graphics, System.Classes, AnimateEasing;

type
  TButtonState = (bs_Down, bs_Normal, bs_Active);

  TNCRSpeedButton = class(TGraphicControl)
  private
    FEasingAnimation: TAnimateEasing;
    FColor: TColor;
    FFromColor : TColor;
    FToColor : TColor;
    FBorderColor: TColor;
    procedure CMMouseDown(var Message: TMessage); message WM_LBUTTONDOWN;
    procedure CMMouseUp(var Message: TMessage); message WM_LBUTTONUP;
    procedure SetBorderColor(aBorderColor: TColor);
    procedure SetFromColor(const Value: TColor);
    procedure SetToColor(const Value: TColor);
    procedure AnimateTickEvent(Sender: TObject; Value: Extended);
    procedure ANotifyEvent(Sender: TObject);
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  public
    Constructor Create(Owner: TComponent); override;
    Destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property FromColor: TColor read FFromColor write SetFromColor;
    property ToColor: TColor read FToColor write SetToColor;
    property BorderColor: TColor read FBorderColor write SetBorderColor;
    property ParentShowHint;
    property ParentBiDiMode;
    property PopupMenu;
    property ShowHint;
    property Visible;
    property OnClick;
    property OnDblClick;
    property OnMouseActivate;
    property OnMouseDown;
    property OnMouseEnter;
    property OnMouseLeave;
    property OnMouseMove;
    property OnMouseUp;
  end;


implementation
 Uses
  System.Math,
  System.UITypes;


{ TNCRSpeedButton }

Constructor TNCRSpeedButton.Create(Owner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(Owner);
  FColor := clBtnFace;
  FBorderColor := clBlue;
  SetBounds(0, 0, 200, 50);
  FEasingAnimation := TAnimateEasing.Create;
  FEasingAnimation.OnTick := AnimateTickEvent;
  FEasingAnimation.OnFinish := ANotifyEvent;
end;

Destructor TNCRSpeedButton.Destroy;
begin
  FEasingAnimation.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TNCRSpeedButton.Paint;
begin

  Canvas.Brush.Color := FColor;
  Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);

  // Drawing Borders

  Canvas.Pen.Color := FBorderColor;
  Canvas.MoveTo(0, 0);
  Canvas.LineTo(Width-1, 0);
  Canvas.LineTo(Width-1, Height-1);
  Canvas.LineTo(0, Height-1);
  Canvas.LineTo(0, 0);

end;

procedure TNCRSpeedButton.AnimateTickEvent(Sender: TObject; Value: Extended);
var
  Ratio: Integer;
begin
  Ratio := 1 - Floor(Value);

  TColorRec(FColor).R := Floor((Ratio  * TColorRec(FToColor).R) + ((1 - Ratio) * TColorRec(FFromColor).R));
  TColorRec(FColor).G := Floor((Ratio  * TColorRec(FToColor).G) + ((1 - Ratio) * TColorRec(FFromColor).G));
  TColorRec(FColor).B := Floor((Ratio  * TColorRec(FToColor).B) + ((1 - Ratio) * TColorRec(FFromColor).B));

  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TNCRSpeedButton.ANotifyEvent(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FColor := FToColor;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TNCRSpeedButton.CMMouseDown(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TNCRSpeedButton.CMMouseUp(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  Invalidate;
  FColor := FFromColor;

  FEasingAnimation.Animating(0, 500, 2000, TEasingType.etBackEaseIn);
end;

procedure TNCRSpeedButton.SetBorderColor(aBorderColor: TColor);
begin
  FBorderColor := aBorderColor;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TNCRSpeedButton.SetFromColor(const Value: TColor);
begin
  FColor := Value;
  FFromColor  := Value;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TNCRSpeedButton.SetToColor(const Value: TColor);
begin
  FToColor := Value;
  Invalidate;
end;

end.
```

I will leave how you solve the black color in the transition to you :).

Comment: Thank you so much, appreciated!

Comment: @nick I hope this gives you some insight about how you could've done it, otherwise translating that C# project is another way to go.

Comment: Yeah thanks! Not a fan of Delphi but work requires it!

Answer (score 2):

The standard `TButton` does not support what you are asking for. It gets its coloring from the OS by default, not the VCL.

You need an owner-drawn button in order to change coloring, like `TBitBtn` or `TSpeedBtn`, otherwise you can subclass `TButton` to manually enable the `BS_OWNERDRAW` window style and handle the `WM_DRAWITEM` notification. Or use a 3rd party skinning framework. Or use VCL Styles if your IDE supports them.

Either way, once you have a button that can change color, you can simply use a `TTimer` to animate the shifting of one color into another as needed.